# setting and accessing global environment variable in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins pipeline view. Say for example the first job is `BUILD` followed by `DEPLOY` and `TEST` job. What I'm trying to achieve here is to have a 'rollback logic' in the test job, meaning when the test job is run and it is successful I want to set current build no as a global environment variable (so that I can potentially access build number from any job) possibly called `TESTED_BUILD_NO`. But if test fails then I want to trigger `DEPLOY` job by passing `TESTED_BUILD_NO` which will deploy last test build.

There is a plugin called [promotion builds plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin), it mentions `PROMOTION_BUILD_NO` variable but when I look at /env-vars.html it is not listed there. I tired looking at api/xml as well but no mention of any promotion variables. Can this logic I mention here be achieved using this plugin? If not how is global environment set and accessed in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are best advised to manage global variables from the system management screens:

Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global Properties
Much more reliable compared to setting these externally to Jenkins.

this can be changed using script or via execute shell/batch.
Or you can use simple groovy scrip to change the value based on Previous command/build status.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using global variables, you can always use `lastStableBuild`, which is automatically set by jenkins. In `DEPLOY` job, use link to `lastStableBuild` from `TEST` job, which form is : `http://JENKINS_ADDRESS/job/JENKINS_JOB/lastStableBuild/`

According to jenkins [wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Terminology):

> **Stable build**  A build is stable if it was built successfully and no publisher reports it as unstable.

Comment: Any idea how can I set report a build as unstable from my test job?

Comment: Usually, dedicated plugin will do it for you. e.g for jUnit test, use JUnit plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin. It will scan and analyze test output. If finds any failure, it reports build as unstable: "Build step 'Publish JUnit test result report' changed build result to UNSTABLE"